# Render React page to html string for print service

Tags: html, reactjs, printing, render

This is a design question instead of a code question. I have a SPA written with React JS and a microservice that takes any html string and print to PDF.

I need to implement a feature that allow the user to click a print button on a page, certain form (majority of current screen) will be printed in PDF format.

My question is how to let React application render to html string so that print service can consume. Server-side rendering? any other approaches? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: ...props.string }}`?

Comment: dangerouslySetInnerHTML does not provide what I need. I have React components/pages. These components/pages should be rendered to html in string and can be used with ajax call to print service. If I know the value that assign to _html,  I can use it for printing.

Comment: @YuMei Did you got the solution?

Comment: see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html - it looks like what you're looking for (but I'm not a React dev, so no guarantees)